# Add id/class to first image in post?

Tags: image, wordpress

I tried the [Luminate](http://www.luminate.com/) image ad, however it added the ad to every single image of the post, and it felt like spam. If I can add a unique id/class to the first image, I can link the Luminate script to that image only.

Edit: I have a wordpress site. I solved this issue in the Luminate settings, by going to apps > image ad options and settings it to 5%. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Please give us more details on what you are trying to accomplish, what your site looks like, some code, anything.